# TouchableOpacity onpress colour - how to change it?

Tags: react-native

When I press my menu the `opacity` makes the button text unreadable? How can I change the button text when `onPress`?

```
   const LYDTouchableAndroid = props => (
      <TouchableOpacity {...props}>
        {props.children}
      </TouchableOpacity>
    );

    return (
      <LYDTouchable
        style={[{ flex: 1 }, marginRightStyle]}
        onPress={() => this.props.onPress(square.scene)}>
        <LinearGradient
          style={styles.square}
          colors={theme.gradients.blueGradient}>
          <Text style={styles.squareLabel}>
            {square.label}
          </Text>
        </LinearGradient>
      </LYDTouchable>
    );
  };
}

LYDSquaredMenu.defaultProps = {
  gradient: theme.gradients.lightBlue,
};

export default LYDSquaredMenu;

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    backgroundColor: theme.colors.white,
  },
  row: {
    flexDirection: 'row',
    marginTop: theme.metrics.buttonsGap,
  },
  square: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
  },
  squareLabel: {
    ...theme.fontStyles.normal,
    color: theme.colors.white,
  },
});
```

Comment: What do you mean by unreadable? Is it the text, or the colour you want to change? `TouchableOpacity` has an `activeOpacity` prop that you can maybe adjust, you can change the color of your text, or worst case look at the [code](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/master/Libraries/Components/Touchable/Touchable.js) and see if you can make a fork that changes the style/text when it's pressed in